# Using Iron Router, "Router is not defined"

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I've added iron-router to my app to handle routing between the home page, an about page and the main page of the app which is a map

After adding iron-router with meteorite,
I wrote a router.js file and placed it in my /client folder, however I'm getting an error that says "Uncaught ReferenceError: Router is not defined "

I checked the error with chrome devtools and it pointed to "Router.configure(..." at the beginning of router.js which I've added below

```
Router.configure({
layoutTemplate: 'layout',
loadingTemplate: 'loading'
});

Router.map( function () {
//the about route
this.route('about', {
    path: '/about',
    template: 'about',
    action: function () {
        console.log('now routing the about template');
    }
});

this.route('home', {
    path: '/',
    template: 'home',
    action: function () {
        console.log('now routing the home template');
    }
});

//the map route
this.route('map', {
    path: '/map',
    template: 'map',
    action: function () {
        console.log('now routing the map template');
    }

});
});
```

Does anyone know why I'm getting the error that Router is not defined?

Comment: I moved the router.js file to the /lib directory so that it would load first.
This broke the app so I then uninstalled and re-installed iron-router with meteorite and the Routing now works within my app.

I hope this can help someone who is stuck in a similar situation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure your meteor version is **0.8.3** or up and use meteorite with command

> mrt add iron-router

Others will cause iron router building errors.

Otherwise, check that your codes of router configure are in Meteor.isClient scope.
If not, just wrap them in client scope.

```
if(Meteor.isClient){
  Router.configure({
   ......
  });

  Router.map(function(){
   ......
  });
}
```

If Iron-Router was installed below version 0.8.3, you should remove them from packages and smart.json,
update meteor with command,

> meteor update

and install iron router again with meteorite.
If no error messages show up, everything goes well

Answer (score 2):

I've had similar issues adding iron-router to Meteor 0.8.3.

This recipe seems to work for me.

- Add iron router to smart.json (or create if new project):

> > {"packages": { "iron-router": {"version":"0.8.2"} }}

- meteor update

At this point iron-router is in the packages folder but may not listed in .meteor/packages list. If not:

- meteor add iron-router

Hope this is helpful

Answer (score 1):

I realize you fixed this, but for documentation purposes:

Putting Iron Router in lib/ directory will allow both client and server to access the code and get's loaded first.

See
[What are the best practices for structuring a large Meteor app with many HTML template files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122977/what-are-the-best-practices-for-structuring-a-large-meteor-app-with-many-html-te)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that `iron-router` is correctly installed but not configured to be used. It just happened to me and I used your question to understand a bit more my issue.

Actually, I had the package present in `package` and in the `smart.json/lock` but it wasn't used in the file `.meteor/packages` and wasn't loaded when meteor started. So it couldn't find it. Just adding the name of the package fixed it.