# Dynamic page rendering in meteor

Tags: meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze

Page rendering is not working with iron:router please help me.Rendering is not working with code.Please find the bellow attached code.And we are users meteor add iron:router 0.9.4.And we used meteor 0.9.3.1. Page rendering is not working

```
<head>
</head>
<body >
    <div>
        {{> players}}
    </div>
</body>

<template name ="editform">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="border-bottom: 5px solid gray;">
        <h2>Profile</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <table>
            <tr>
               <td>First name:</td>
               <td><input type="text" name="pff_name"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Last name:</td>
               <td><input type="text" name="pfl_name"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Email Address:</td>
               <td><input type="email" name="pfemail"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Phone number:</td>
               <td><input type="text" name="pfname"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Company or Organization:</td>
               <td><input type="url" name="pfname"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>        
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<template name="players">
     <div>
         <table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered table-hover no-margin">
             <tr>
                <th>IP</th>             
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            {{#each scorers}}
            <tr>
                <td><a href="{{ pathFor  'editform' }}" >{{ ip }}</a></td>              
                <td></td>
            </tr>
           {{/each}}
       </table>
    </div>
</template>
```

This router.js

```
Router.route("/", function() {
    this.render("route");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear what you are trying to achieve.
May I suggest you to start by reading the [Meteor Docs](http://docs.meteor.com/) for starters.

For a simple app like this one you can use a structure like this: 
/client (client side code files) 
/server (server side code files) 
collections.js 
[Check out a good way of structuring your app here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122977/what-are-the-best-practices-for-structuring-a-large-meteor-app-with-many-html-te)

First, you don't need the `<head>` and `<body>` tags here.
Then, you can create a layout template in client folder in which you can set the players template to render, also to add header, footer, etc to your page.
**layout.html**

```
<template name="layout">
    {{>players}}
</template>
```

Then you need a players template in client folder as well.
I'm gonna go ahead and produce an simple example here to get you going. The user input value is collected, inserted into *Players collection* and for each player in that collection a new table row is created in `div.result` using a *{{players}}* helper.
**players.html**

```
<template name="players">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" style="border-bottom: 5px solid gray;">
            <h2>Profile</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>First name:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="pff_name" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Last name:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="pfl_name" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <button class="insert">Submit</button>
        </div><br/>
        <div id="result">
          <table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered table-hover no-margin">
            <tr>
              <th>First Name</th>
              <th>Last Name</th>
            </tr>
            {{#each players}}
            <tr>
                <td>{{firstname}}</td>
                <td>{{lastname}}</td>
            </tr>
            {{/each}}
          </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

**collections.js**

Create a new Meteor Collection called Players, which will store all the added documents.

```
Players = new Meteor.Collection("players");
```

**players.js**

Here, the *players* helper will return a cursor and a created Meteor method named *addPlayer* is called.

```
Template.players.helpers({
    players: function() {
        return Players.find();
    }
});

Template.players.events({
    'click .insert': function(event, template) {
        var first = $('#pff_name').val();
        var last = $('#pfl_name').val();
        if(first !== "" && last !== "") {
            Meteor.call("addPlayer", first, last);
        }
        $('#pff_name').val("");
        $('#pfl_name').val("");
    }
});
```

**server.js**

Adding the player to Players collection

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    Meteor.methods({
        addPlayer: function(fname, lname) {
            Players.insert({firstname: fname, lastname: lname});
        }
    })
});
```

**routrer.js**

Tell Iron Router to render the players template

```
Router.map(function () {
    this.route('players', {
        path: '/',
        template: 'players',
        layoutTemplate: 'layout'
    })
});
```

**EDIT:**
You are using IronRouter version 0.9.4, **but** your route is defined for the new version.
Either update IronRouter to *iron:router@1.0.0-pre3* **or** follow the notation I gave for this version.

Comment: Thank you for your response actually i need the page rendering in meteor.@durrrr

Comment: I'm not following. This is meteor. @user2740350

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to be blunt, but you really need to read [this](http://eventedmind.github.io/iron-router/).

At the very, very top it says:

```
Router.route('/', function () {
  this.render('Home');
});
```

> When the user navigates to the url "/", the route above will render the template named "Home" onto the page.

You have the line `this.render("route");` in your router, but no template named "route".

Comment: sorry this is the right one. this.render("editform").Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: sorry this is the right one. this.render("editform").Please help me. Thanks in advance.@richsilv