# Meteor collection fetch returns empty array but is subscribed

Tags: meteor, publish-subscribe, meteor-collections

I uninstalled the autosubscribe and restarted the meteor app. Since then, I haven't been able to access my collection data on the client.

Every question related to the empty array return comes up with the same answer: *the subscribed data isn't available yet*. But no matter how long I wait I never see the data on the client.

Server:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
  Meteor.publish("states", function () {
    return states.find();
  });
});
```

Logging `states.find().fetch()` on the server spits out my states as expected.

On the client:

```
Meteor.subscribe("states", function(){
  console.log(states, states.find(), states.find().fetch());
});
```

`states` and `states.find()` return objects as expected, `.fetch()` returns an `[]`.

Waiting (even several minutes) then running `states.find().fetch()` in the browser console gives me `[]` still.

Thoughts?

**EDIT**

Collection is declared outside of the isServer/isClient blocks (to utilize schemas).

```
states = new Meteor.Collection("states");
```

Comment: How did you declare your collection?

Comment: @BrendanTurner Added to op

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are getting `[]` because you are publishing the data on the startup, when isn't ready, lets make that subscribe reactive.

```
Tracker.autorun(function(){
   Meteor.subscribe("states", function(){
      console.log(states, states.find(), states.find().fetch());
   });
});
```

**OPTIONAL**

There is no reason to declare the collections inside the `isServer/isClient` if statements

Since you are starting with the Good practices (removing `insecure/autopublish` packages)

Lets do the follow.

First Create the folder structure. (check [meteor/structuringyourapp](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp) and this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122977/what-are-the-best-practices-for-structuring-a-large-meteor-app-with-many-html-te/13039681#13039681)).

Inside the `appName/lib/collection.js` put this code.

```
states = new Meteor.Collection("states");
//optional you can place this subscribe inside the appName/client/main.js
if(Meteor.isClient){
   Meteor.subscribe("states", function(){
      console.log(states, states.find(), states.find().fetch());
   });
}
```

and on the `appName/server/publish.js`

```
Meteor.publish("states", function () {
    return states.find();
  });
```