# Meteor publish/subscribe not working

Tags: meteor, meteor-publications, meteor-collections

I'm working in meteor 1.7, and my publish/subscribe is returning only empty arrays.
file structure:

```
-all/
  -shared.js
-client/
  -main.js
-imports/
  -Elsewhere.js
-server/
  -main.js
```

shared.js:

```
Chats = new Mongo.Collection('chats')
```

client/main.js:

```
Template.main.onCreated(()=>{
  Meteor.subscribe('chats')
});
```

server/main.js

```
Meteor.publish('chats', function(){
  console.log(Chats.find().fetch()) //Shows that I have documents in the collection
  return Chats.find();
});
```

Elsewhere.js

```
Template.Elsewhere.helpers({
  chats(){
    console.log(Chats.find().fetch()) //[]
    return Chats.find().fetch()
  }
})
```

Why don't I get what I'm publishing?

-------------------------------------New stuff-----------------------------------

I'm now unsure if it's a load order issue, reactivity issue, pub/sub issue, or a mix of them. I have this snippet

```
search(collection, where, id, part, callback){
  var result
  if(id){
    console.log(Meteor.users.find().fetch()) //[]
    result = Collections[collection].findOne(id)
  }else{
    result = Collections[collection].find(where ? where : {}, {many:true}).fetch()
  }
  if(result){
    if(callback){
      callback(result)
      return
    }else{
      if(part){
        return result[part]
      }else{
        return result
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm also noticing that the output from this log is happening BEFORE my subscriptions. This file is located in /imports/scripts/tools.js

Comment: Maybe your helper is executing before your subscribe is executed.
Try putting your subscribe inside an autorun block like here: http://blazejs.org/guide/smart-components.html#Subscribe-from-onCreated

Comment: @GaëtanRouziès Nope, no change

Answer (score 1):

Inside an autorun block subscribe to 'chats' and check if handler is ready. Then find and fetch.

```
this.autorun(() => {
    let handler = Meteor.subscribe('chats');

    if(handler.ready()) {
         console.log(Chats.find().fetch())
    }
  });
```

Comment: Anything inside the ```if(handler.ready())``` block never runs

Comment: Ok, I had a typo, now it runs, and I get subscribed... Sorta... The log in client/main.js logs correctly, but I still get an empty array everywhere else in the app

Comment: Insert something into your chats collection and check the changes

Comment: Same behavior as before, logs correctly in main, and wrong in elsewhere

Comment: Try with tracker: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28890672/meteor-collection-fetch-returns-empty-array-but-is-subscribed . Also remove **autopublish**

Comment: Same thing, I don't understand why functionality is changing between my main.js, and a js that's imported by main.js

Answer (score 1):

I realized that I was not using a reactive data source for my helpers, I was setting a Session variable when I called the tool.search function, which only ran once.